# Modify x-frame-options in apache2

Tags: iframe, apache2

I want to use an iframe in my localhost web server (wamp).
This iframe loads a form from a remote web server.

I have access to the remote web server, it uses apache2 (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html), and i modify its security.conf file and i load the module 'headers'.

I modify security.conf by this line (the ip is the ip of my local computer):
Header append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://localhost, http://172.18.48.120, 172.18.48.120"

But when i test the changes, always says the same:
Refused to display 'http://externalURL.net/form.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Any idea? Where's the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness:

Here are the lines to add to your `apache2/conf-available/security.conf` file to make your iframed content available in browsers supporting either or both **X-Frame-Options** and **Content-Security-Policy** header options (as stated on [this survey site](http://erlend.oftedal.no/blog/tools/xframeoptions/))

> Header set X-Frame-Options: "ALLOW_FROM https://www.example.com"
>   Header set Content-Security-Policy: "frame-ancestors
>   https://www.example.com"

Make sure that header module is enabled

```
a2enmod headers
```

restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

That's it !

Comment: Thanks. Whenever I added those lines to security.conf, `apachectl configtest` told me there was a syntax error. Enabling header module did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i solved it, the solution is:

- Load module headers in apache2.
- Modify file security.conf, you have to append this line:
  Header set X-Frame-Options 'ALLOW-FROM http://externalURL.net'
  (it's a valid option if you use a local web server, e.g. wamp:
  Header set X-Frame-Options 'ALLOW-FROM http://localhost')
- Reload service apache2.
- If you want to test it, don't use Google Chrome, it ignores x-frame-options directive and it always says the same message:
  Refused to display 'http://externalURL.net/form.php' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
  It's ok with Firefox.